# Migrate Freehand files to Adobe Illustrator

Tags: graphics, adobe-illustrator, cs3

I have *rudimentary* skills in scripting that I got from free lessons, so I'm sorry in advance.

I got [this script from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/thankyou.jsp?ftpID=4706&fileID=4383) (particularly to use in CS3).

I work in CS6 but have access to CS3 & CS4, if that helps (I've tried it in CS3 & CS6 but get the error).

The task of hand-migration 20 years of FH files to ai is daunting (opening each file on an old PowerPC in CS3, exporting as eps or ai, then opening on a new mac). While I understand Macs only do up to 1000 files at a time, that's much better, if I can get this script to run rather than giving this:

**ERROR: 21, undefined is not an object**

I opened it in ExtendScriptToolkit to see if anything leapt out at me but I'm afraid my meager skill set has failed.

Comment: Most scripting systems tell which statement generated the error, or they have a debug mode for running the script and that should highlight the place where the error occurs. Which line in the file is reported with the error? You need to give us more information for us to help you.

Comment: I came here from a Search result as this is still a much needed request by us FreeHand users. Backlogs of hundreds of FreeHand files have left many in need of conversion to CS6 and CC versions of Illustrator. As of this date today, there is progress being made on a third-party converter. I am one of the beta-testers and have successfully converted my FH test-files to CC. Still some quirks with proper text rendition and gradations. Also, a batch function is not yet implemented but is on the developer's list—once the bugs are cleared. A release date will likely be this summer

Answer (score 1):

Look at this bit of the code:

```
// Set Freehand options
var FreehandOptions = app.preferences.FreeHandFileOptions;
FreehandOptions.convertTextToOutlines = false;
FreehandOptions.importSinglePage = false;
```

Since Illustrator CS6 doesn't support freehand file formats, there is no "FreeHandFileOptions" so it will never work in CS6. The script was written for CS4 but it still works in CS5.1.